# Нужен ли дополнительный знак перед "этой" (см.)?

Tags: пунктуация

> **О том**, что ребёнок не может не ходить в школу, **этой** глобальной темы мы
>   не касались. А каким образом он налаживает отношения со сверстниками?
>   Как они выстраиваются?

Из записи радиопередачи, переносимой на "бумагу".

Comment: Многоточие (или точка, если первая часть на слух воспринимается как тезис), а "Этой" - в следующее предложение. Если же непременно запятая, то и тире (но так менее складно воспринимается - видно, что вторая часть сказана вдогонку начатому).

Comment: Спасибо. Беру тире!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что **грамматика предложения здесь неверная**, а содержание трудно понять их короткого отрывка. Если не касались темы, то к чему относятся эти вопросы? Пока не касались (присоединительная конструкция), а сейчас коснемся?

Как вариант: **Ребёнок  не может не ходить в школу  – этой глобальной темы мы (пока) не касались.** А каким образом он налаживает отношения со сверстниками? Как они выстраиваются?

Comment: **Из записи радиопередачи, переносимой на "бумагу".** Передача часовая, речь - живая, с запинками и перескоками мысли, - мне весь текст переписывать?

Comment: Если дословная запись устной речи, то нет вопросов.  А перед  "этой" тире ставится в обязательном порядке (предложение с именительным темы).

Comment: Еще ближе к тексту: То, что ребёнок не может не ходить в школу, — этой глобальной темы мы не касались.